# How can I transform a vector into a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a vector j

```
j = [3 4 5 6 7]
```

I need to obtain a symmetric matrix that contains a diagonal of ones, distributing the vector `j` as shown in this case:

```
ans =

 1     3     4     5     6     7
 3     1     3     4     5     6
 4     3     1     3     4     5
 5     4     3     1     3     4
 6     5     4     3     1     3
 7     6     5     4     3     1
```

Comment: You need to concatenate 1 with your vector and use the solution in the duplicate target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clc; close all; clear all;
X = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; % The given vector 
A(1, :)= X;
for n = 2:length(X)   
    temp = circshift(A(n - 1, :), 1);    
    A(n, :) = [X(n), temp(2:end)];    
end
disp(A);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what `toeplitz` is for:

```
>> toeplitz( [1 j] )
ans =
     1     3     4     5     6     7
     3     1     3     4     5     6
     4     3     1     3     4     5
     5     4     3     1     3     4
     6     5     4     3     1     3
     7     6     5     4     3     1
```

Comment: was happy to get your rep to 33,333 :-)

Comment: @bla lol, thanks :p